# Center button vertically in bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html. I'm using the Bootstrap 3 framework. I am trying to vertically align my button with the h2 heading in row. The problem is the button is aligned with the top of the column div rather than in the middle like the heading. Also when the screen is resized to smaller, the button becomes aligned with the bottom. I have a link to a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/n74/c9dhn9nc/17/

```
<div class ="row">  
      <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" >
           <button  class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Create App</button>
      </div>
  </div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a margin to the button to center the button to the h2 tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9dhn9nc/19/

```
.tmargin {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, is there a way to simply center both elements vertically ie vertical-align:center; doesn't seem to work on the button

Comment: Bootstrap is a bit of a different animal, I usually use javascript for centering vertically in bootsrap since you never really give a height to the containers. What I usually do is have a script that gets the height of the parent and the center it based off the height.

Comment: But, if you find a bootstrap gu-ru they might have a way better solution then mine, this is just how I would do it.

Comment: One problem is when I resize the screen to a smaller display this breaks as the button now goes to the bottom

Comment: Do you want the column to break?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by that, just wanted the button to stay same level as the heading even on the smaller screen

Comment: use "col-sx-3" instead of "col-sm-3" in the class, look at the fiddle I made in the answer, I changed those.